# Убрать эффект нажатия на элемент при скролле RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-scrollview

Мой `RecyclerView`, с атрибутом `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` находится в `ScrollView`. При скролле своего экрана, я замечаю эффект "нажатия" элемента, за который я держусь при скролле. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону думать или гугулить, чтобы убрать данный эффект при скроллинге? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: так вы это не уберете именно при скролле. откуда приложение знает, вы "скролите" или "нажимаете"? как только вы коснулись экрана - сработало "нажатие". начали вести пальцем? нажатие off, скролл on. вы можете написать свою кастомную разметку item'ов. но тогда не будет НИКАКОГО эффекта нажатия.

Comment: Похоже, это стандартное поведение. Посмотрите как пролистываются списки в любых других приложениях.